# Response didn't contain a server id

Tags: vaadin

I'm using Vaadin 14 for an application that loads data from a database. I hava a AGrid object which loads data through a DataProvider and it uses a filter on the date.

When I set the filter in certain conditions I receive the error in the title but I cannot find no additional information about the origin of the error, Can someone please help me?

I tried changing Vaadin version, upgrading to the last v14 but with no success, I also tried to debug the application but I can't follow the flow to the origin of the error, it semmes to be fired by some Vaadin class

Comment: Is "Response din't contain a server id" the error you get in the client (only)?

Comment: Also, if you think that Vaadin eats up an error around the data provider (since filtering triggers it), you should check two things: first do your own try/catch in the count/page methods of the data provider and if there is no problem, make sure, that whatever count/page return, actually match.  E.g. are there enough items per page for the declared count.

Comment: Some stack traces, error messages would help identify the cause of the problem. But most probably it's an exception in your Dataprovider which is not correctly handled in your code

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I'll try to investigate in that direction

Comment: We finally discovered the issue, there was a Npe caused by a null in a database row, ti was an issue in the data. Thank you for the help